# Copy values from one table to another where same ID

Tags: mysql

I am working with a table  of 1000+ rows where data in two columns has been corrupted (`table_corrupted`). Luckily I have an outdated backup of that table where these two columns are intact (`table_outdated`). So I thought: Why not just replace the values in those two columns and leave the rest as it is?

Let's say `table_corrupted` & `table_outdated` both have 5 columns:

`id`(INT), `name`(TEXT), `lat`(DOUBLE), `lon`(DOUBLE), `comment`(TEXT)

```
insert into `table_corrupted` (`lat`,`lon`) 
select `lat`,`lon` from `table_outdated`
WHERE `table_corrupted`.`id` = `table_outdated`.`id`;
```

...results in this error: **"Unknown Column 'table_corrupted.id'In Where Clause"**

After some research I found out this is because SQL is evaluated backwards, from right to left. To be honest, I did not figure out a solution - any advice? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have mis-diagnosed this.  Try looking up UPDATE statements instead (these let you change existing values in existing rows, rather than inserting new rows).

Comment: You're perfectly right, MatBailie! I'm with stupid :-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can better join the tables and simply update the values in your corrupted table by executing the below query

```
update `table_corrupted`
inner join `table_outdated` on `table_corrupted`.`id` = `table_outdated`.`id`
set `table_corrupted`.`lat`= `table_outdated`.`lat`,
`table_corrupted`.`lon`= `table_outdated`.`lon`
```

Comment: @MatBailie:- Yes that seems to be correct. Updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Dont use insert. Use update. This one worked for me.

```
UPDATE `table_corrupted` INNER JOIN `table_corrupted` ON (`table_corrupted`.`id` = `table_outdated`.`id`) 
SET `table_corrupted`.`lat` = `table_outdated`.`lat`, `table_corrupted`.`lon` = `table_outdated`.`lon`
```

Comment: not working for me: **Not unique table/alias: table_corrupted** - even after using the database name too. But Rahul Tripathi solved it anyway. Thanks a lot for your quick answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ON DUPLICATE:

```
insert into `table_corrupted` (`id`,`lat`,`lon`) 

    select `id`,`lat`,`lon` from `table_outdated`
    on duplicate key update table_corrupted.lat = table_outdated.lat, table_corrupted.lon = table_outdated.lon
```

or an update:

```
update table_corrupted,table_outdated
set table_corrupted.lat = table_outdated.lat, table_corrupted.lon = table_outdated.lon
where table_corrupted.id = table_outdated.id
```